# How to find out in Flutter when a Widget appears / disappears?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to find out in a stateful widget when the whole widget appears on screen or disappears, similar to iOS onViewWillAppear / disappear. Is that possible somehow? I didn't find anything related in the Flutter docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What your looking for is in the `flutter_widgets` package

Add the following to your `pubspec.yaml`

`flutter_widgets: ^0.1.7+1`

Inside this package is a widget called `VisibilityDetector` it requires a `key`, a `child`, and a function `onVisibilityChanged`

```dart
return VisibilityDetector(
key: Key("1"),
onVisibilityChanged: (visibility) {
//This will give you a range of values between 0 and 1,
//0 being not visible and 1 being fully visible.
print(visibility.visibleFraction) 
}
child: Container(
width:double.infinity,
height: 300,
   ),
),
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are thinking to perform something after widget build, You should use below code:

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
if (SchedulerBinding.instance.schedulerPhase ==
    SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks) {
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => onWidgetBuild());
}

/// appear
void onWidgetBuild() {
/// This block will be called onWidgetBuild
/// do your code here
}

/// disappear
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  /// release whatever you have consume
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck using the [focus_detector package](https://pub.dev/packages/focus_detector). A `FocusDetector` widget will need to be placed within the default `build()` function and your existing UI code made it's child:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) =>
    FocusDetector(
      onFocusLost: () {

      },
      onFocusGained: () {

      },
      onVisibilityLost: () {

      },
      onVisibilityGained: () {

      },
      onForegroundLost: () {

      },
      onForegroundGained: () {

      },
      // Your previous build code replaces the Container() below
      child: Container(),
    );
```